# retrieve LocalResource key and pass to Html.ActionLink linkText

Tags: model-view-controller

i want retrieve LocalResource key and pass to Html.ActionLink linkText.but i dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the strongly generated class by visual studio:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Resources.SomeKey, "Home", "Index") %>
```

Or for a more general solution take a look at this [post](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/10/ASPNET-MVC-Simplified-Localization-via-ViewEngines.aspx).

Comment: 1. i can't use LocalResources?